# I can`t to get the userinfo

Tags: oauth, google-oauth, userinfo

Help me please. I have tried get a user information from googleApis. But I get error already.
My error:
{
"error": {
"code": 401,
"message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth2accesstoken, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See [https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project."](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.%22),
"status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
}
}

I use this method

```
var userInfoUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo";
var hc = new HttpClient();
hc.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", access_token);
var response = hc.GetAsync(userInfoUrl).Result;
var userInfo = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

This I get access token:

```
string codeClient = "code=" + code + $"&client_id={googleclientid}&";
            string secretUri = $"client_secret={googleusersecretkey}&" + $"redirect_uri={googleredirect}&"
                 + "grant_type=authorization_code";
            string postString = codeClient + secretUri;

            string url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url.ToString());
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

            UTF8Encoding utfenc = new UTF8Encoding();
            byte[] bytes = utfenc.GetBytes(postString);
            Stream os = null;

            request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
            os = request.GetRequestStream();
            os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

            HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Stream responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader responseStreamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
            var result = responseStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
            var parametrs = result.Split(',');
            return parametrs[0].Replace("\"", "").Remove(0, 18);
```

when I do request from https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo Then I get response

```
{ 
"issued_to": "MyClientId", 
"audience": "MyClientId", 
"scope": "googleapis.com/auth/drive", 
"expires_in": 3549, 
"access_type": "offline" 
}
```

This token is OK

Comment: can you show how you are creating the access token